# Building iOS6 app with Titanium SDK 3.1.3

Tags: ios, titanium, ios7, command-line-interface, titanium-mobile

I'm using Titanium SDK 3.1.3, XCode 5, and have simulators for both iOS 6.1 and iOS 7.
I'm trying to build an iOS 6.1 app in the simulator via the Titanium CLI but I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] Invalid --ios-version value '6.1'

Accepted values:
   7.0
```

Which is odd because the release notes for the SDK says "You will still be able to compile iOS 6 apps with Xcode 5. Additionally, Xcode 5.0 requires Mac OS X 10.8.4 or later."

Thanks in advance for your inputs.

Comment: A work around to this "bug" i've used is to reinstall Xcode 4.X and change the name to X-code 4 in my applications folder and set it to the default Xcode with this command `sudo /usr/bin/xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode-4.app/`

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But isn't it cumbersome if you need to build for different version of iOS on a regular basis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad — a proper SDK was missing inside Xcode's folders:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk

Comment: mine are there, but Titanium still can't see them (but iOS7)